# Set Div height Dynamically based on highest content in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs in a row. I want to set height dynamically to each div based on the highest content in div. Height should be equal to all divs.
Can you all please help me to solve this with javascript/jquery?

Below is the code:

```
 <div class="table-cellprop">
  <div class="bottom-pane">
      <div class="content-info">
      <p>some imp text  </p>
      <h3>title </h3>
      <div class="text-left"> some text with info
        <h4>title 2 </h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="bm-list"> li one  </li>
          <li class="cm-list"> two </li>
          <li class="mm-list"> three </li>
        </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="table-cellprop card-btm">
  <div class="bottom-pane">

    <div class="content-info"> TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText </div>

  </div>

</div>



<div class="table-cellprop card-btm">
  <div class="bottom-pane">

    <div class="content-info"> TextTextTextText </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? tried googling this? "equal height columns"

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need javascript. You can use flexbox.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.table-cellprop {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-cellprop:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #b9f6ca;
}
.table-cellprop:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #84ffff;
}
.table-cellprop:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #b388ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="table-cellprop">
  <div class="bottom-pane">
      <div class="content-info">
      <p>some imp text  </p>
      <h3>title </h3>
      <div class="text-left"> some text with info
        <h4>title 2 </h4>
        <ul>
          <li class="bm-list"> li one  </li>
          <li class="cm-list"> two </li>
          <li class="mm-list"> three </li>
        </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="table-cellprop card-btm">
  <div class="bottom-pane">

    <div class="content-info"> TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText </div>

  </div>

</div>



<div class="table-cellprop card-btm">
  <div class="bottom-pane">

    <div class="content-info"> TextTextTextText </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Harley for your answer. I am using this structure in slider, flex box is not working in my slider structure. Can you please give solution how can I handle it through Javascript?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample fiddle of your current code